# Trying to collect data from local files using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to run a python script to parse html files and collect a list of all the links with a `target="_blank"` attribute.

I've tried the following but it's not getting anything from bs4. SoupStrainer says in the docs it'll take args in the same way as findAll etc, should this work? Am I missing some stupid error?

```
import os
import sys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from unipath import Path

def main():

    ROOT = Path(os.path.realpath(__file__)).ancestor(3)
    src = ROOT.child("src")
    templatedir = src.child("templates")

    for (dirpath, dirs, files) in os.walk(templatedir):
        for path in (Path(dirpath, f) for f in files):
            if path.endswith(".html"):
                for link in BeautifulSoup(path, parse_only=SoupStrainer(target="_blank")):
                    print link

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
if path.endswith(".html"):
    htmlfile = open(dirpath)
    for link in BeautifulSoup(htmlfile,parse_only=SoupStrainer(target="_blank")):
        print link
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something stupidly simple that I've overlooked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The usage `BeautifulSoup` is OK but you should pass in the html string, not just the path of the html file. `BeautifulSoup` accepts the html string as argument, not the file path. It will not open it and then read the content automatically. You should do it yourself. If you pass in `a.html`, the soup will be `<html><body><p>a.html</p></body></html>`. This is not the content of the file. Surely there is no links. You should use `BeautifulSoup(open(path).read(), ...)`.

**edit:** 
It also accepts the file descriptor. `BeautifulSoup(open(path), ...)` is enough.

Comment: I knew it'd be simple! Thank you!