# How can I find multiple URLs within a string (href attribute)

Tags: python, regex

I've written a script [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574119/trying-to-collect-data-from-local-files-using-beautifulsoup) to get all the URLs from within a template directory, however some of the hrefs contain two URLs to use depending on what language the app runs in.

So my script currently gives me a list of whatever is in `href='here'`, but now I want to also collect the URLs from a href that looks like this;

```
href="{{ 'http://www.link.com/blah/page.htm'|cy:'http://www.link.com/welsh/blah/page.htm' }}"
```

What regular expression would I need to return those? (As with so many people, I'm awful at Regex!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
href="{{ 'http://www.link.com/blah/page.htm'|cy:'http://www.link.com/welsh/blah/page.htm' }}"

import re
print re.findall("'(http://(?:.*?))'", href)
# ['http://www.link.com/blah/page.htm', 'http://www.link.com/welsh/blah/page.htm']
```

Takes anything starting with http:// that's inside apostrophes.

Comment: +1 You can also add `http(s)?` to handle both http and https.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yup, or just `s?` will do it... Suppose it should be up to the OP if they want to handle that/any other protocols...

Comment: Wonderful. I was trying to find by start and end characters. Does `re.findall("'(http[s]://` work to match http and https? I've seen the `[s]` used in an example, but don't fully understand it.

Comment: @marksweb sorry - was out for moment. `[s]` means match one of the characters inside the `[]` therefore it would only match https - Using `s?` means match none or one s... so it matches http or https